# UITextBox Height

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have a question about altering the height of a UITextField. I have already made the object in Interface Builder and the height is fixed as 31. I have searched around on the net and this doesnt seem to be a popular thing to do.

[link to apple dev page](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html)

Regards @norskben.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I answered my own question.

The default textfield with the curly edges is the only one that cant be resized.

Design wise I am using a label to provide a white backing.

[Source](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/3390-increasing-height-uitextfield.html#post17970)

Comment: Check the check mark next to this answer so the system will know the question is answered. It is allowed to answer your own question.